# How can I create the smallest possible mirror of the archive?

Tags: system-installation, xen, mirrors

I need to create an http url at my laptop to have a Ubuntu installation in my laptop on a Xen environment. [This is what the final thing will look like](http://bderzhavets.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/install-ubuntu-intrepid-server-pv-domu-at-xen-33-port-via-httpgetco-centos-52-dom0/).

The host and client are both going to be my laptop. I Googled and came across apt-mirror and some other packages. I do not want to archive the entire 15 GB Ubuntu repositories on my machine.

It is not possible to use a CD, ISO, loop mounted disk. I have tried using netboot image on local machine which failed because if you are attempting to create a virtual machine on a hardware which does not support VT virt-manager installer necessarily needs a URL of this sort

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/

Any other option to create guest OS is simply grayed out.

My Ethernet connections do not work when I boot with Xen-4.0 and a pv-ops Dom0 kernel from Jeremy's tree. Which is where I have to do this work. So I have to create a URL structure which is similar to Ubuntu mirrors. So how can I do this in bare minimum so that at least the console boots and once the console comes I can do some work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [apt-mirror](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apt-mirror) [image: Install apt-mirror] you can get it down to only 7.5 GiB.

You can comment out the source, updates, security, universe and multiverse repositories in its config file, `/etc/apt/mirror.list` This leaves you only with the contents of main. As main contains everything that is shipped on the different CD images, it should be enough to get you installed. It might not be the smallest solution, but it's probably the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

This answer provides to way of doing what you are asking. https://askubuntu.com/a/154580/1110324

> ## local repository method.
>
> There is a lot more easier method than using AptOnCD. Though I have included AptOnCD method as the question talked about that.
> Copy all .deb files into the target computer
>
> You need to copy all .deb files you download from /var/cache/apt/archives folder to a suitable folder in your target Internetless computer. I recommend you to copy all the files in a folder named debs which itself resides in a folder named LocalRepo. Meaning, .deb files are in LocalRepo/debs folder. You can put the LocalRepo folder wherever you wish. Let say, for example, I have put it in my home directory i.e. /home/anwar.
>
> So, the folder structure is like below:
>
> ```
> -/
>  -/home
>    -/anwar
>     -/LocalRepo
>      -/debs
> ```
>
> where debs folder contains all the deb files you downloaded.
>
> ## Generate packages index file
>
> Open a terminal and go to the folder just above the Debs folder. In this example, it is /home/anwar/LocalRepo.
>
> Run this command: while you are in LocalRepo folder.
> `apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages`
> It will create a Packages file in the LocalRepo directory.
>
> ## Add your local repository in the repository source list
>
> Open /etc/apt/sources.list file with root privilege
> `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.`
>
> ```
> At the top of sources.list file, put a line like this.
>
> `deb file:/home/anwar/LocalRepo /`
>
> replace /home/anwar/LocalRepo with actual directory name where you put the LocalRepo folder.
> ```
>
> Save the file, and exit gedit.
>
> ## Update package indexes to be able to install from Local repo
>
> Run `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal, It will create a repository source list about available repositories. So, your newly created Local Repository will be recognized.
>
> ## Install packages from local repository.
>
> ```
> Then run `sudo apt-get install package-name`
> (replacing package-name with actual package) to install your desired repository.
> ```
>
> Note: You will always be warned about being your repository is not "Authenticated" one. In this case you can ignore such warning, since you created repository from packages of "Authenticated" sources, meaning Official Ubuntu Package archive.
>
> You can override this warning by putting --allow-unauthenticated switch in the command. such as
>
> `sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated package-name`
>
> ## Creating a trusted repository instead:
>
> If you want to create a trusted local repository, You should [read this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090731). It is very simple and very good one about the topic

Edit: I found that when sharing the repro using the steps above, I needed to pass `-o Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true` the the apt commands to get it to work.