# Download latest version of deb package

Tags: repository, deb

I want to setup local package repository mirror, with manually selected packages. 
Is there any automated way to download latest version of specific package from repository, giving name, distribution and architecture ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/531403/how-to-download-all-repository-using-apt-get this you meant?  or using a dvd/cd is possible to https://askubuntu.com/questions/154536/install-a-mirror-without-downloading-all-packages-from-official-repository

Comment: This solution requires to have the same system, distribution and architecture on downloading machine. I'd like to be able to download i.e Debian stretch arm64 from Ubuntu amd64.